# Red and Green color channels are swapped in ffmpeg rendered video

Tags: ffmpeg, opengl, rgb

I'm using code similiar to [this](http://blog.mmacklin.com/2013/06/11/real-time-video-capture-with-ffmpeg/) to pipe OpenGL image data directly to ffmpeg.  I'm using this readpixels call:

`qglReadPixels( 0, 0, glConfig.vidWidth, glConfig.vidHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0 );`

however I have to use GL_RGB instead of GL_RGBA.  In the ffmpeg command line I change RGBA to RGB24 accordingly.  However, the output videos color channels are messed up (red is swapped with green).  I can't seem to find any color formats that are GRB, so is there some way to swap red and green channels in ffmpeg using `colorchannelmixer` ?

edit: this would involve setting RR to 0, RG to 1, GG to 0, GR to 1? What would the syntax for that be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that only the red and green channels have to be swapped, use

```
colorchannelmixer=rr=0:rg=1:gr=1:gg=0
```